# how to monitoring home router traffic

Tags: networking, home-networking

I have a domestic router (BT HUB 5) and I have a few devices connected to it, including a PS4. if I want to monitor the network package coming in and out of the PS4. how can I do it?

I have used wireshark on PC, I guess it doesn't have a PS4 or embedded version is it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a DDWRT, tomato, or openwrt (opensource firmware) compatible hub/switch and connect it to yours.  Plug yours into it, and plug everything else into the new device.

Now monitoring can be done with standard linux tools.
You can setup dhcpd so it hands out static IP to your devices.

Then iptables can do byte/packet counting.

tcpdump can generate a wireshark compatible file you can open on your PC.

From there it depends on what you want to monitor, and how closely.  Also how many gigabytes of data you can handle sifting through each day.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to set up a shared connection on your PC, and connect your PS4 to your PC instead of the router.  Then you can use Wireshark on the interface the PS4 is using to monitor its traffic.

This requires that you have at least 2 different network interfaces on your PC that can connect to your router, and at least one of those interfaces is suitable to connect to your PS4.

Comment: upvode. this question is also very good, but the accepted answer just slightly better.